# How to save styled text in Database and retrieve the same styled text onto JEditor Pane

Tags: java, swing, sql-server-2005, jeditorpane

Can anybody give me any idea, if i can store a text attribute (like bold, italic etc) modified in JEditorPane in MSSQL SERVER Database? 
The user should be able to modify the text attribute, then store that in DB and again retrieve them from DB when in need, in the same attribute style.

Comment: You could set the content type to "text/html" and use HTML as the text of the JEditorPane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define proper EditorKit. E.g. `HTMLEditorKit` will allow you to store text as HTML with all styles info. Just use getText() and setText() to work with formatted content.

ALternatively you can write own Reader/Writer see for exmple http://java-sl.com/editor_kit_tutorial_reader_writer.html